# docker swarm compose placement constraints boolean or condition

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Is it possible to specify a boolean or condition in the placement constraints of docker composes?
I'm looking for something that can emulate this syntax:

```
services:
  service1:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - <condition1> || <condition2>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've looked for this, but after 1 year and 6 months, Swarm still doesn't support the 'or operation'.

Therefore, the current equivalent operation is to group all other labels except the condition into 'not equal' operations.

if you want label == (1 | 2) then..

```
constraints:
  - label != 3
  - label != 4
  ... 
  - label != n
```

This looks bad but is currently the only possible way in swarm.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible. You can't do what you want.

Answer (score -4):

You can specify the condition as:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
          - engine.labels.operatingsystem == ubuntu 14.04
```

Please refer https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-constraints---constraint

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#mode

Comment: isn't this a boolean AND?

Comment: As per the docker docs, "Multiple constraints find nodes that satisfy every expression (AND match)".
So I think Yes.

Comment: well, I'm looking for a boolean OR

Comment: I did not find any, can you please try with single pipe as 
(“none”|”on-failure”|”any”)
because there are other settings in docker-compose which take this as:


--restart-condition  Restart when condition is met (“none”|”on-failure”|”any”) (default “any”)

Comment: Weird to see this down voted , when as you know , you can't do OR logic , but this answer contains all you need to achieve your desired results . Use negative logic to make the proper AND statements that are equivalent to an OR . Or use the many properties that can be tested in a placement constraint , including labels that are set based on the same OR conditions . `if isHere OR isManager label = 'ManagerHere'` . Then test for that label in the constraints .

Comment: @LostNomad311 If the answer was the comment you just gave, I might not have downvoted it. But as it stands, it's very misleading. (That being said, I don't understand your comment. You can't just rewrite all ORs to ANDs. You want to add new labels that represent the ORed condition?)